# Use Sainsmart SSR to control AC outlet with Arduino?

Tags: arduino

I am looking for a way to control an AC outlet with my Arduino Uno.

I have looked around and found the following: http://amzn.com/B0057OC66U

I heard you can use this to control 16 AC outlets with this an arduino but I have not found any sites that explain how to do this. How can I do this? If possible, please explain for a beginner.

Comment: It's not very well documented - I've seen a couple of reviews where folk have slated it becuase they had to figure it out themselves or they are awaiting documents from the manufacturer

Comment: I haven't even boughten it yet Brian. I wanted to be sure this would work before I invested into it. Do you or anyone have a suggested alternative? I've found things like this: https://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Product_10001_10001_176719_-1 but I'm not even sure how many outlets it can support or how to wire it to the arduino

Comment: @Alex  FYI. Check out the [proposed specialized Arduino board](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/49538/arduino) on SE. I bet, they would benefit from your participation.

Comment: I suggest you chech tghis out https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10747

Comment: Well, one thing to note is the linked PCB is **not** solid-state. It uses old-fashioned electromechanical relays.

Comment: Oh, also, SainSmart is a terrible place for beginners to buy stuff. You basically get the board. Period. To get it working, you generally have to reverse-engineer the board enough to figure out enough of the circuit to determine how to properly wire it. I'd reccomend you buy something similar from Sparkfun, Adafruit, or somewhere that caters more to inexperienced people (i.e. they actually provide instructions/schematics/any documentation).

Comment: The [PowerSwitchTail](http://www.powerswitchtail.com/) looks fairly nice. It's pretty inexpensive ($25 assembled, $19 as a kit), and the mains wiring is done for you, so there is less risk of injuring yourself.

Comment: @connorwolf I have seen that but $25 feels a bit too steep just to connect only one outlet...

Answer (score 1):

The Amazon Item page Reviews are incredibly helpful for these items, not just the 16 channel, but the 8 and 4 and 2 channel ones by the same manufacturer. Some even have videos. They have it all figured out. The Item page also has the PCB layout and schematic available, though it's not as clear as it could be. You might want to look at some of the reviews for the other versions as well just to get a hang of them.

The J2, 2x10 header is for connection from your Arduino. Pins 1 and 2 are 5 V out (You could power your arduino off the 5 V out), pins 2-18 are Relay 1-16 control, and Pins 19 and 20 are Ground. Logic level Low turns the relay on. Current is about 0.3 mA to 3 mA per channel. Logic Level High is 5 V, so make sure you have 5 V tolerant outputs on your Arduino.

The 16 Channel board takes 12 V, and I'd recommend 1 A just to be on the safe side. From a review:

> * Input Power (12 VDC input)***
>
> - About 8 mA is required with all relays off.
> - Each relay requires about 30 mA when on.
> - So max supply current is 8 mA + (16 x 30 mA) = 488 mA (actual measured was 500 mA)
> - Because one may use the board's +5 VDC output (2 pins) to power an Arduino/PIC circuit, use a 12V power supply that can provide MORE than
>     500mA (depending on your circuit's requirements).
> - Note that the switching regulator on the Relay Board should somewhat efficiently (say 70%?) convert the board's 5V power usage to 12 V
>     power input requirements. For example: 200mA at +5VDC (1 Watt) does
>     NOT mean the +12V supply needs to supply an additional 200 mA also.
>     This is because 1 W of power from the +12V supply only requires about
>     83 mA ( 12 V x 83 mA = 1 W ); however at say 70% efficiency of the 5 V
>     regulator, this goes up to about 120 mA (83 mA / 0.7) but NOT the full
>     200 mA.
>
> > NOTE: The best way to discover what 12 V supply is needed (its max current rating) is to ACTUALLY MEASURE the 12 V input current while
> >     using a "test supply" that can more than handle worst case (with all
> >     relays ON) then buy the supply that meets your needs. Always use a
> >     modern "switching" supply (wall wart) because they are smaller, way
> >     more efficient, generate little heat, and normally use much less
> >     "vampire power".

**This is an AC relay board, so you could kill yourself if you mess something up.**